# Extracting comma separeted values to make new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a df with only one column.  The dtype is `object`:

```
column_1
1,2,3
2,3,4
```

I want to extracted those comman separeted values to make new columns,like this:

```
 column_1     column_2    column_3    column_4
    1,2,0.3        1           2          0.3
    2,3,0.4        2           3          0.4
```

I tried something with `.split(',')`  but it's failed.

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `split`

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.column_1.str.split(',').tolist(),index=df.index))
Out[275]: 
  column_1  0  1  2
0    1,2,3  1  2  3
1    2,3,4  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

use split with the expand=True option

```
txt="""
column_1
1,2,3
2,3,4
"""
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt),sep='\n')
df[['column_2','column_3','column_4']]=df['column_1'].str.split(',',expand=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
0    1,2,3        1        2        3
1    2,3,4        2        3        4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
df[["Column_%d"%i for i in range(2,5)]] = df['column_1'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```